# Tomcat7 invalid expression

Tags: java, tomcat7, el

I am trying to migrate our web application to Embedded Tomcat 7, getting following error for

```
<c:out value="${delegator.getId()}"/>
```

Error

```
"${delegator.getId()}" contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: Error Parsing: ${delegator.getId()}
```

Following expression is working fine, only above one is not working

```
<c:out value="${delegator.getDisplayName()}"/>
```

Based on the other post , I tried to run the tomcat with following option but still I get the error

```
 -Dorg.apache.el.parser.SKIP_IDENTIFIER_CHECK=true
```

**Delegator Bean:**

```
/** The id. */
private String id;
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

Comment: What is `delegator`? Perhaps the object does not contain the `getId()` method?

Comment: Matt, it does, updated in the post.